prompt the user for array size
What happens if the program asks the user to enter the size of the array while the size of the array has been initialized to zero first?
This was my code:
int size = 0;

int arr[size];

scanf("%d", &size);

I was expecting to have an array with the size that user entered. But it did not work properly.

Interesting. If you have say int y = 0, x = y + 1; scanf("%d", &y); and the user enters 42, do you expect x to become 43?

Statements in C do not establish a set of relationships (unlike spreadsheet formulas). They are instructions done once. So int arr[size]; has already defined an array of zero size (which is not allowed by Standard C) and there is nothing that you can do to change it, except by recompiling the source code. Similarly in real life. If you want to nail a board to the wall, you have to hold up the board before you drive in the nail.

You have a zero element array. Not very useful and you're getting into undefined behavior territory, which you want to steer well clear of.
You need to either use variable length arrays:
size_t sz;
scanf("%zu", &sz);
int arr[sz];

Or you want to dynamically allocate the array using malloc:
size_t sz;
scanf("%zu", &sz);
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * sz);

// Stuff...

free(arr);

Remember that you can't count on scanf or malloc succeeding, so check their return values and handle errors as required.
Consider the second malloc example which makes it easier to test that the array is properly created. First we want to read inputs until we get a valid size.
#define MAX_SZ 32768

size_t sz;
while (scanf("%zu", &sz) != 1 || (sz == 0 || sz > MAX_LEN)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
}

But this will leave erroneous input in the buffer to be read over and over again, so we want to read a line and parse data from it until we get a valid input.
#define MAX_SZ 32768
#define LINE_LEN 1024

size_t sz;
while (1) {
    char line[LINE_LEN];

    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input failure.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (sscanf(line, "%zu", &sz) == 1 && (sz > 0 && sz <= MAX_SZ)) {
        break;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
}

// We now can proceed knowing that sz was
// successfully read and falls into a reasonable range. 

Clearly the devil is in the details, but taking this extra effort pays off later.
You then simply need to ensure that malloc succeeds.
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * sz);

if (!arr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Array could not be allocated.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Do stuff with the array safely knowing it allocated properly.

free(arr);


Just a nice alternative to arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * sz); --> arr = malloc(sizeof arr[0] * sz);.

"you can't count on scanf or malloc succeeding" is interesting in that you can't count on int arr[sz]; either. Checking that for success is problematic.
